# Saving object in SharedPreference as Json and Key Changes

Tags: android, json, sharedpreferences, apk

I have my app in PlayStore. When I update my app with new exported apk SharedPreference Key is changing. You can understand it by seeing the json strings given below.

I am saving an object in shared preference as given below.

- Saving user details in SharedPreference.

  ```
  Gson gson = new Gson();
  String json = gson.toJson(user);
  prefsEditor.putString("user", json);
  prefsEditor.commit();
  ```
- Getting details from sharedPrefernce

  ```
  Gson gson = new Gson();
  String json = myPref.getString("user", null);
  Log.v(MainActivity.TAG, "Json == "+json);
  user = gson.fromJson(json, User.class);
  ```

Please have a look on the jsons i am printing, the keys are changed to 'a','b' etc.

- When I run normally the JSON is  `Json == {"accessToken":"12345678","country":"India","countryCode":"91","email":"","firstName":"Aneesh","lastName":"Kamalone","nickName":"Kamalone","notificationId":"","phoneNumber":"******","profilePic":"","uniqueId":"","userId":"*****","userLatitude":14.9,"userLogitude":79.6}`
- When I update with the previous version the json is `Json == {"a":"****","b":"Aneesh","c":"Kamalone","d":"Kamalone","e":"**********","f":"","g":"APA91bElQulddjH6xSR0WH8nfBGcFIbn-sRe-ChkhIx1c6Il05_wwGrTLm1QDNsr6TtaG1bIrICmXKhK1I8ZVzo0cqvwPWSj4NrxJKyzTsdPpNlizmGMaJfMWj_rjteP6yNoRFeDAZYfTCyhx-7WUAmTT2rX0q1S6Q","h":"","i":"12345678","j":"India","k":"91","l":14.9,"m":79.6,"n":""}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seams that you are using **proguard** and it obfuscates your `User` class.

`Gson` uses field names as keys by default. So I suggest to use `@SerializedName` annotation for correct json mapping

Comment: I was not enabled proguard. Your answer helped me to remember about proguard.

Comment: I'm using proguard. What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

It is my mistake.**proguard** was not enabled when I was exporting the APK.